# Windows 7 Gadget not releasing ActiveX object

Tags: javascript, excel, activex, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm working on a Windows 7 gadget that needs to pull data from an excel document.  The problem is, is that the Excel process won't unload after I've retrieved the data I need.

Here's the code I use in my initialization function:

```
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = false;
    Excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    var workbooks = Excel.Workbooks;
    var workbook = workbooks.Open("\\\\SERVER\\Documents\\Sample.xlsx", 0, true);
    var activesheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
    var cell = sheet.Cells(1, 1);
    var value = cell.Value;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = value;
    delete value;
    value = null;
    delete cell;
    cell = null;
    delete activesheet;
    activesheet = null;
    delete workbook;
    workbook = null;
    delete workbooks;
    workbooks = null;
    Excel.Quit();
    delete Excel;
    Excel = null;
```

This is all wrapped in a try-catch block and I can verify that it's all succeeding.  All the deletes and null assignments are my attempt to release any references to the COM objects, but I seem to be missing something.  Is there some way I can force the Excel process to unload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just how Internet Explorer/JScript works — references are held for a period of time until the garbage collector runs.  The reference *should* be garbage collected after a while if you set the variable to `null`.  You can also force it to be collected by using the (relatively undocumented) `CollectGarbage()` method available to JScript and IE:

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

//... blah ...

Excel.Quit();
Excel = null;
window.setTimeout(CollectGarbage, 10);
```

Note that you need to leave a small amount of time (10ms here) before calling `CollectGarbage()`, otherwise when you call the function the variable may not have been marked for collection yet.

> **Related support article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266088**

Comment: Note that I tested this just now in a desktop gadget and can confirm it does remove the process from the process list.

Comment: Awesome - sorry this took a while for me to get around to testing, but it works as expected now.

Comment: @Eclipse: no problem at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Microsoft Office installed on my current machine, but I believe you have to change `Excel.Quit()` to `Excel.Application.Quit()`.

This is because Excel is initialized as an ActiveX Object, specifically `Excel.Application`, and not `Excel` by itself.